# Is there a way to check if all elements of a list are contained in another list in racket?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I want a function that does something like this:

```
>(function '(1 2 3 4) '(1 2 3 4 5))
#t
```

When in this case is returning #t because all elements of the first list are contained in the second list. Is there a function that does that without having to worry about order?

Comment: Is this in plain racket ? also does the order matter? like would (function '(1 2 3 4 5)  '(1 2 3 4)) return #f ?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that the elements of the first list have to be contained in the second list, that would be indeed return #f. Using #lang play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I know there is no built in function for this, and I believe the shortest way to define such function would be something like this.

```
(define (list-check l1 l2)
  (andmap (λ(x) (not (boolean? (memq x l2)))) l1))
```

Comment: Great, is memq the same thing as member?

Comment: mostly memq uses eq? function for comparison so it kind of addresses the pointers racket have somewhere back there so you get absolute equality. There are bunch of these memv etc. that compares differently you can read about them all in the documentation

Comment: Every pair is a `#true` value and every miss is `#false` so `(andmap (λ(x) (memq x l2)) l1)` would suffice.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you aren't comparing the lists as *lists*, but as *sets*, so it would make much more sense to use a structure designed to be used that way. Racket provides [hash sets](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28tech._hash._set%29) in its standard library. This makes the function you're looking for trivial.

```
(define (list-subset? a b)
  (subset? (list->set a) (list->set b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `memq` works swell on small lists, however since we have hash tables available we might as well use them:

```scm
(define (list-check-hash l1 l2)
  (define hash (make-hasheq))
  (for-each (λ (x) (hash-set! hash x #t)) l2)
  (andmap (λ (x) (hash-ref hash x #f)) l1))

;; test
(define test 
  (let loop ((x 1000000) (acc '()))
    (if (zero? x) acc (loop (sub1 x) (cons x acc)))))

(list-check-hash test test)       ;==> #t
(list-check-hash test (cdr test)) ;==> #f
```

Of course you may choose to use immutable ones instead since it's more idiomatic and still a lot faster than `memq`:

```scm
(define (list-check-hash l1 l2)
  (define hash (make-immutable-hasheq (map (λ (x) (cons x #t)) l2)))
  (andmap (λ (x) (hash-ref hash x #f)) l1))
```