# boolean function for a sublist in scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need make a boolean function for evaluating two list,for example:

```
   (define list1 '((1 2) (4 5) (8 6) (2 8)))
   (define list2 '((1 2) (8 6)))
```

`list2` is a sublist of `list1`, and must returned `#t`, but I don't know how do it, I try with this function for comparing two list

```
(define (sublist? lst1 lst2) 
  (if (null? lst2)       
      #f                
      (if(list? (car lst2)) 
         (sublist? lst1 (car lst2))
         (if (and(equal? car(lst1) (car lst2)) (equal? cdr(lst1) (car lst2)))   
            #t (sublist? lst1 (cdr lst2))))))
```

help :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if all elements of a list are contained in another list in racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322565/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list)

Answer (score 1):

This `sublist?` behaves as a "subset?".

```
; sublist? : list list -> "boolean"
;  return non-false if all elements of xs are in ys
(define (sublist? xs ys)
  (or (null? xs)                 ; the empty list is a sublist of ys
      (and                       ; for a non-empty list 
       (member   (car xs) ys)    ;   the first element must be in ys
       (sublist? (cdr xs) ys)))) ;   and the rest of the elements as well.
```

This `sublist?` behaves as a "substring?"

```
; prefix? : list list -> boolean
;   is xs a prefix of ys?
(define (prefix? xs ys)
  (or (null? xs)
      (and (equal?  (car xs) (car ys))
           (prefix? (cdr xs) (cdr ys)))))

; sublist? : list list -> boolean
;   is xs a consecutive sublist of ys?
(define (sublist? xs ys)
  (or (null? xs)
      (prefix? xs ys)
      (and (not (null? ys))
           (prefix? xs (cdr ys)))))
```

Comment: Much nicer than my impl. - just need to switch the order of the arguments (he's checking if list2 is a sublist of list1). big plus one! :)

Comment: One small issue though, if you'll ` (define list2 '((4 5) (2 8)))` it'll return `#t`. That said, I found the same bug in my impl. as well...

Comment: Both `(4 5)` and `(2 8)` are elements of `list1` so `#t` is what I expect it to be.

Comment: well... that's not the definition of "sublist" as I know it... :)

Comment: @sebastian What kind of `sublist?` do you need?

Comment: according to your definition `(define list2 '((8 6) (1 2)))` is a sublist of `(define list1 '((1 2) (4 5) (8 6) (2 8)))` ;)

Comment: Yes. (Nonsense to reach the required number of characters)

Comment: Would it make sense to compare it to "substring" then ?  I wouldn't expect "ba" to be considered as a substring of "abc".

Comment: Sure. Both meanings make sense. The question is which one Sebastian had in mind.

Comment: makes sense in what way? the classic definition of substring says that "ba" is *not* a substring of "abc" (and I'm pretty sure that sublist follows the same lines). What you're saying is more relevant when discussing groups/sets and inclusion relationship - where order doesn't matter.

Comment: In the sense that both operations are useful (in different contexts). The one I used makes sense when lists represent sets.

Comment: I added a "substring?" version too.

Comment: Too bad I can't do another "plus one" :)

Answer (score 0):

A suggested solution:

```
(define list1 '((1 2) (4 5) (8 6) (2 8)))
(define list2 '((4 5) (8 6)))

(define (sublist? lst1 lst2)        
      (if (null? lst2)
          #t
          (if (and (null? lst1) 
                   (not (null? lst2)))
              #f
              (if (list? (car lst2))
                  (or (and (sublist? (car lst1) (car lst2))
                       (sublist? (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2)))
                      (sublist? (cdr lst1) lst2))
                  (if (eq? (car lst1) (car lst2))
                    (sublist? (cdr lst1) (cdr lst2))
                    (sublist? (cdr lst1) lst2))))))

(sublist? list1 list2)
```

**Explanation**:
This is (not) simply handling all the edge-cases:
 - If `list2` is null - it is always a sublist of `list1`
 - If we got to the end of `list1` and `list2` is not yet found - return false
 - If `(car list2)` is a list - we need to check recursively two cases: if `(car list1)` equals to `(car list2)` or if `(car list2)` is somewhere else in `(cdr list1)`
 - If `(car list1)` and `(car list2)` are the same - we'll check recursively with the rest of both lists: `(cdr lst1)` and `(cdr lst2)`

This answer was tested [here](http://cs61a.org/assets/interpreter/scheme.html)