# I want to find whether list1 is contained in list2; also known as a sublist, but i am having trouble with the ending part of my code

Tags: racket, sublist

;;the problem is that i want to compute whether a-list is contained in another-list regardless of size 
`;;(list=? (list 1 2 3) (list 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 4))` should produce true, but for my program it does not.

please explain/fix where I went wrong
my code is:

```
(define (list=? a-list another-list)
   (cond
       [(empty? a-list) (empty? another-list)]
       [(cons? a-list)
              (and (cons? another-list)
              (and (= (first a-list) (first another-list))
                   (list=? (rest a-list) (rest another-list))))]))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if all elements of a list are contained in another list in racket?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29322565/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-all-elements-of-a-list-are-contained-in-another-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward in Racket, just use the [`subset?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fset..rkt%29._subset~3f%29%29) procedure:

```
(define (list=? a-list another-list)
  (subset? a-list another-list))


(list=? (list 1 2 3) (list 2 2 2 2 3 1 2 3 4))
=> #t
```